# How can i delete pending generation expires status certificate from my provisional profile

Tags: iphone, ios, certificate

I want to create certificate in my iPhone developer account. I've uploaded CSR file but it tooks long time in uploading and now expires status is showing pending generation.

I don't to how can i delete that certificates? Anybody help me please.

Image :: http://www.2shared.com/photo/64RX8-BU/2013-06-04_1649.html

Thanks!
Shailesh

Comment: I got that problem too. I requested certificate few minutes ago. I think they have an outage.

Comment: me too, now have 17 pending requests for a single app!

Comment: same problem with me too...let us know if this is working for someone

Comment: I think the issue was from apple's server. It's working now.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like all you can is to wait. There is a problem on Apple side.
Read here: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5080033
And here: https://discussions.apple.com/message/22163396?tstart=0#22163396?tstart=0